# How can I combine these lines in htaccess?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A bot is visiting my website and leaves in 0 seconds so makes 100% exits. I'm trying to prevent this using an htaccess file in Wordpress.

The first lines blocks direct access of ref attack,
and the second lines prevents spam domains,

but they don't work together.
How can I combine these lines in htaccess?

I have updated the code and entered the complete htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On 

# ref spam block
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(ref=.*)?\ HTTP [NC, OR]
RewriteRule .? http://www.hqtunes.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-as\.net [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-us\.net [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-eu\.net [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*hulfingtonpost\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*apanews\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*adcash\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*aliexpress\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*bestwebsitesawards\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*buttons-for-website\.com   [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*bycontext\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*cenokos\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*cenoval\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*cityadspix\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*darodar\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*econom\.co [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*edakgfvwql\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*gobongo\.info [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.info [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.org [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ilovevitaly\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*iskalko\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*jollygame\.net [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*luxup\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*max-start\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*o-o-6-o-o\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*o-o-8-o-o\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*priceg\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*savetubevideo\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*screentoolkit\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*semalt\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*seoexperimenty\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*slftsdybbg\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*socialseet\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*superiends\.org [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*vodkoved\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*websites-reviews\.com [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*websocial\.me [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*ykecwqlixx\.ru [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*simpleshare-buttons\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L] 
</IfModule> 

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer uptime-as.net spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer uptime-us.net spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer uptime-eu.net spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer hulfingtonpost.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer apanews.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer adcash.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer aliexpress.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer bestwebsitesawards.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer buttons-for-website.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer semalt.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer bycontext.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer cenokos.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer cenoval.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer cityadspix.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer darodar.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer econom.co spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer edakgfvwql.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer gobongo.info spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ilovevitaly.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ilovevitaly.org spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ilovevitaly.info spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ilovevitaly.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer iskalko.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer jollygame.net spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer luxup.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer max-start.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer o-o-6-o-o.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer o-o-8-o-o.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer priceg.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer savetubevideo.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer screentoolkit.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer seoexperimenty.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer slftsdybbg.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer socialseet.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer superiends.org spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer vodkoved.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer websites-reviews.com spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer websocial.me spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer ykecwqlixx.ru spammer=yes 
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer simpleshare-buttons.com spammer=yes 

Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
Deny from env=spammer
```

Comment: what is `ref attack`? and what apache version are you using?

Comment: The bot decreases my website's SEO ranking by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this single combined rule with multiple `OR` clauses:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(ref=.*)?\ HTTP [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-as\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-us\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*uptime-eu\.net [NC,OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*hulfingtonpost\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a line for htacess. So I couldn't add that line. Thats why I have updated my question and added the complete htaccess. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: See updated answer. I didn't add all the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}` lines in my answer to make it more readable. Concept is same. You keep adding `OR` clause in all of them except the last `RewriteCond`.